# Movable time window constrained by fixed time window on fixed time window

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a set of jobs.

A job is requested by a customer.
The customer delimits times (for example: "You can start at 8:00 and finish at 13:00).
An internal algorithm will produce an estimated execution time for this job (even if this job has 5 hours, this guy can do the job in 2 hours).
This means the guy can do the job from 8:00 to 10:00 or from 10:30 to 12:30.

In the time window of a work day **(8:00 to 17:00)**, we will try to assign jobs to a list, then assign this list to a worker. There are multiple lists and workers.

The only constraint on the lists, is that we can't execute two jobs at the same time. (But, for example, you can have a **J1(8:00 to 12:00, execution time 1 hour) and J2(8:00 to 12:00, execution time 2 hour)** it is doable. Because J1 can be done from 8:00 to 9:00 and then J2 can be done from 9:00 to 11:00)

In javascript, my object has a start time, an end time, and the estimated duration **(using the useful and powerful moment.js)**.

A list is simply an array with a specialised push that returns true if the job can be added.

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53I0p.png)
 Here is an example where we have brown jobs with their red estimated execution time, they are on the time window of the day (in black).
The top job is the last inserted, the thing to do is to try to know if the list of jobs still doable. So what here need to be done is just to slide (green arrow) the execution time for a bit later, between the two other jobs. 
First of all, I'm trying to find a way to know if a job can be inserted in a list of jobs.

Then I did an algorithm where execution time is always **ASAP** in the job window time, but I think I can improve this.

Is there any suggestion on a proper way to satisfy constraints and allow a maximum of jobs to be inserted in a list?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try think some solutions first, on a paper or something, and after, if you cannot find any, try some research.

> Tip:  Try to Sort things, and see if it helps to make decisions.

This is a classic algorithm problem, you should look for `Scheduling Algorithms`, and see some approaches.
Check this out, too.
http://www.ctl.ua.edu/math103/scheduling/scheduling_algorithms.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive example (which could be made iterative as a stack) with bit representation for the timeline and duration in half-hours. It exhausts all possibilities, exiting early if there's no fit (of course, if there is a fit, you could just output the first one and exit rather than returning all as in the example).

```js
function toBin(start,duration){
  return ((1 << duration) - 1) << (start - 8) * 2
}

function f(i,list,timeline,jobs){
  if (i == jobs.length){
    console.log(list);
  } else {
    for (var j=jobs[i].start; j+jobs[i].exec/2<=jobs[i].end; j+=0.5){
      var bin = toBin(j,jobs[i].exec)
      if (!(bin & timeline)){
        var _list = list.slice();
        _list.push("("+i+","+j+")");
        f(i + 1,_list,timeline | bin,jobs);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```js
var example = [{start:8, end:12, exec:2}, {start:8, end:12, exec:4}]

f(0,[],0,example);

/*
(job index, start time)
(0,8),(1,9)
(0,8),(1,9.5)
(0,8),(1,10)
(0,8.5),(1,9.5)
(0,8.5),(1,10)
(0,9),(1,10)
(0,10),(1,8)
(0,10.5),(1,8)
(0,10.5),(1,8.5)
(0,11),(1,8)
(0,11),(1,8.5)
(0,11),(1,9)
*/
```